# At what tenses can I use the "to be going to" and "used to" constructions?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, tense

There are constructions like:

to be going to

used to

be used to

get used to

At what tenses can i use them?
For example
"to be going to" in past simple looks well: I was going to...
But "to be going to" in future simple probably looks strange: I will be going to...

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what your asking. Can you focus on one question and explain clearly what your doubts are?

Comment: I was editing the content of the question. Hope it's easier to understand

Comment: It's not what you can or can't use, it's what you want to *say* that should come first. How would you say something about a future event? I will get used to it. How about the past? I was used to going to the market on Wednesdays. You get the idea.

Comment: _I am going to_ already refers to the future, so no-one ever says _I will be going to_ (except when _go_ is used in its literal sense - _When I am on holiday I will be going to bed late_).